# Show that function converges uniformly. I tried to maximise the function, but got stuck expressing the x.

Tags: uniform-convergence

So, here is the function: $\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$. I try to find the max of the function by deriving it: $\frac{1}{n}(1+x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \cdot nx^{n-1} = x^{n-1}(1+x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$. I tried to take natural logarithm of the function: $(n-1)\ln x + (\frac{1}{n}-1)\ln(1+x^n) \Rightarrow \ln x = -\frac{1}{n} \ln (1+x^n) \Rightarrow x = -\frac{1}{n}(1+x^n)  $

I assume the way I am trying to solve it is incorrect, what could be the way to determine the uniform convergence?

Comment: Converges uniformly on what domain? Not the whole of $\mathbb R$, right? Think about the Binomial theorem.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The domain is given as $[0, \infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if $ x $ is a real such that $ x\leq 1 $, then $ \sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1 \cdot $

If $ x\geq 1 $, then $ \sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}x \cdot $

Thus, $ \left(f_{n}\right)_{n} $ converges (pointwise) to a function $ f $ defined us follows : \begin{aligned}f:\mathbb{R}_{+}&\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\ x&\mapsto\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} 1&\textrm{If }x\leq 1\\ x&\textrm{If }x\geq 1\end{matrix}\right.\end{aligned}

Let $ n $ be a positive integer, we have : \begin{aligned} \left(\forall x\leq 1\right),\ \left|f\left(x\right)-f_{n}\left(x\right)\right|=\sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}}-1&=\frac{x^{n}}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(1+x^{n}\right)^{\frac{k}{n}}}}\\&\leq\frac{1^{n}}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(1+0^{n}\right)^{\frac{k}{n}}}}=\frac{1}{n} \end{aligned}

\begin{aligned} \left(\forall x\geq 1\right),\ \left|f\left(x\right)-f_{n}\left(x\right)\right|=\sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}}-x&=\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(1+x^{n}\right)^{\frac{k}{n}}x^{n-1-k}}}\\&\leq\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(1+0^{n}\right)^{\frac{k}{n}}1^{n-1-k}}}=\frac{1}{n} \end{aligned}

Thus, $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right)\left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}\right) $, we have that : $$ \left|f\left(x\right)-f_{n}\left(x\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n} $$

Hence $$ \left\Vert f-f_{n}\right\Vert_{\infty}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Which makes it possible to conclude that $ \left(f_{n}\right)_{n} $ converges $\textbf{uniformly}$ to $ f $ on $ \mathbb{R}_{+}\cdot $

Comment: first, I don't understand why do you divide $x^n$ by sum of $(1+x^n)^{\frac{k}{n}}$? And for the second expression, where $x \ge 1$ it's even more confusing to me, why do you choose to divide 1 by $(1+x^n)^{\frac{k}{n}} x^{n-1-k}$? Thank you.

Comment: I did just used a well known identity. Given $ a,b\in\mathbb{R} $, and $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, we have : $$ a^{n}-b^{n}=\left(a-b\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{a^{n-1-k}b^{k}} $$

Thus, if $ n $ is an integer different from $ 0 $, and $ a,b $ are reals, we have the following : $$ \sqrt[n]{a}-\sqrt[n]{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right)^{n-1-k}\left(\sqrt[n]{b}\right)^{k}}} $$

I did all that, just because I wanted to get rid of the nth root, it's a special case of multiplying by the conjugate, when $ n $ is $ 2\cdot $